# How to combine several movieclips into one scene?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, cs3

I'm creating a website that allows kids to designs a tshirt.  I will have four section, colour, graphic, text and print.

I have created these sections on demos and they are all working.

I now need to properly create them all on one movie clip.

I'm having problems with it, when i select the chosen tshirt colour and move onto the graphic section the shirt is white again and hasnt came through blue.  Its the same for every section, when I select a grahic they dont come through either etc when I click the next button it refreshs the page.

Does anyone know how to create this kind of design on one movie clip using different frames and so that the colour etc transfers onto each new page?

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store the values that you need as variables in the parent MovieClip. Then when you go between sections you check what these are and update the new section accordingly.